# Create view with calculations in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-view

I'm trying to create a view through phpmyadmin. It contains some calculations.
like

```
Select A,B,C,D,E, (IF(E>0,B,C)+A+D)
```

How am i able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create view view_name -- provide an appropriate name for view
as 
select A,B,C,D,E, (IF(E>0,B,C)+A+D) as total
-- include from table if required
-- from my_table
```

**Refer to**:
[***MySQL: CREATE VIEW Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

> ```
> CREATE
>     [OR REPLACE]
>     [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
>     [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
>     [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
>     VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
>     AS select_statement
>     [WITH [CASCADED | LOCAL] CHECK OPTION]
> ```